# How to add an item in a collection in amazon s3?

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, boto3

I have  this code  for create a data collection:

```
import boto3

def createCollection():
        cliente = boto3.client('rekognition')
        respuesta = cliente.create_collection (CollectionId = 'Fotos')
        print (respuesta)

createCollection()
```

But my question is how to add an item in this collection.
Could you please help me. 
thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you're trying to add an image to the collection from your local filesystem, you can do so with the [`index_faces()`](http://boto3.readthedocs.io/en/latest/reference/services/rekognition.html#Rekognition.Client.index_faces) method:

```
with open('image.png', 'rb') as image:
    respuesta = cliente.index_faces(Image={'Bytes': image.read()}, CollectionId='Fotos')
    print respuesta
```

Comment: No problem! just don't forget to accept the answer if you are satisfied with it